# Jquery - else if to show text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/mn77f/6/

I want it to show a message when their are no fields (questions). I tried to implement this with the following addition:

```
    } else if (x == 0) { < p > No additional questions < /p>
}
```

Which can be seen in the fiddle above. It however doesn't work and stops the whole thing working.

The log says: `Unexpected token <`

How should I have implemented this?

Comment: fiddle is 500. but, you can't just jump in and out of JS/HTML like you can with PHP, you need to do something with the text, probably by setting the html of an object such as jQuery("p#message_element").html("No additional questions");

Comment: Must be jsfiddles fault, still working fine on mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change

```
< p > No additional questions < /p>
```

to

```
$("<p>No additional questions</p>").insertBefore(InputsWrapper);
```

jsFiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/mn77f/7/

Comment: It doesnt show the text on my screen

Comment: @Jimmy your else if block never executes because there is a text box by default in the inputsWrapper therefor else if (x == 0) never happens cause x = 1;

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should put html strings in double or single quotes like this:

```
'<p>No additional questions</p>'
```

then create a paragraph element and give it an id, so that you can update its value to what you need or make it an empty paragraph if your validations have passed.

```
<p id="infoP"></p>
```

and then do this to update its value:

```
 $('#infoP').html('<p>No additional questions</p>');
```

or this to set it to an empty paragraph:

```
 $('#infoP').html('');
```